# Always enabling numeric instability correction with Gurobi

Tags: gurobi, cvxpy

We run large-scale optimization problems on regular-basis using Cvxpy+Gurobi.

Our optimization problem sometimes (~10% of the time) becomes numerically unstable.

Fortunately, the issue automatically resolves after re-running the optimization problem with setting of [Gurobi's numeric instability correction parameter](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/numericfocus.html), i.e. `NumericFocus=3`.

We were curious on:

1. To avoid re-running it the second time, can we always by-default  enable the numeric instability correction parameter `NumericFocus=3`?
2. Other than slightly higher runtime, is other any other downside also?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, please read [Guidelines for Numerical Issues](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/guidelines_for_numerical_i.html) in the Gurobi Optimizer Reference Manual. In short, there is far more to numerical issues than just setting a magic parameter. If you are a commercial customer, you can contact Gurobi Support for specific guidance on your models.

Comment: Thanks Greg! We had gone through the article but it enlists general guidelines for handling Numerical issues, whereas we were specifically interested towards downsides of `NumericFocus=3`.

Comment: Is there any downsides, other than [performance impact](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/making_the_algorithm_less_.html#:~:text=computations%2C%20which%20can-,impact%20performance,-.%20The%20NumericFocus%20parameter)) ?

Comment: It's hard to summarize the entire chapter in a few sentences, but:

1. In general, numerical issues are best handled by reformulating the model, not via solver parameters; remember the adage "garbage in, garbage out"

2. Numerical issues not only lead to slow performance but can also lead to wrong answers.